# Auto center ticks and values on graph when there's only one with chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

The graph looks perfect when there are multiple values, but when there's only  value to show it's on the left axis and I'd like it to be centered and grow from the center like so:

[image]

These are my options:

```
const options = {
         scales: {
            xAxes: [
               {
                  gridLines: {
                     display: false
                  }
               }
            ],
            yAxes: [
               {
                  borderColor: "rgba(15, 15, 15, 0)",
                  gridLines: { display: false },
                  id: "A",
                  position: "left",
                  scaleLabel: {
                     display: true,
                     fontColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)",
                     labelString: "€ Revenue"
                  },
                  ticks: { fontColor: "rgba(15, 15, 15, 1)" }
               },
               {
                  borderColor: "rgba(15, 15, 15, 0)",
                  gridLines: { display: false },
                  id: "B",
                  position: "right",
                  scaleLabel: {
                     display: true,
                     fontColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)",
                     labelString: "Impressions"
                  },
                  ticks: { fontColor: "rgba(15, 15, 15, 1)" }
               }
            ]
         }
      };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it:

```
const options = {
     scales: {
        xAxes: [
           {
              offset: true, // <-- THIS
              ticks: { fontColor: "rgba(10, 31, 68, 1)", fontStyle: "bold" }
           }
        ],        
     }
  };
```